# parse class objects in tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I want display this data in my tableview (this is data I am getting from parse backend), how can I do this?

```
(
    "<TestObjectJaswanth: 0x7f90d16e6250, objectId: XGxjBUhtXU, localId: (null)> {\n    foo = bar;\n}",
    "<TestObjectJaswanth: 0x7f90d16f31f0, objectId: hVa6gykrs4, localId: (null)> {\n    foo = jaswanth;\n}"
)
```

But the app is crashing, can someone help me out with this problem?

```
PFObject *tmepobject  = [dataarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.lbl.text = [tmepobject objectForKey:@"foo"];
```

Comment: Can you post the crash report?

Comment: -[__NSCFConstantString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1002951a0
2015-10-20 18:13:02.749 tablwviewwithheader[5287:183419] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1002951a0'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: Please edit your question to include the error that you are getting.

Comment: @JaswanthKumar Looking to your crash log `PFObject ` is string not dictionary.  Does your class have `objectForKey:` function? Show your `PFObject` class

Comment: what i need to show?

Comment: -(void)retrierfromParse{
    
    PFQuery *playername = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"TestObjectJaswanth"];
    [playername findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            NSLog(@"%@",objects);
            dataarray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:objects];
            
        }
        [self.tableView reloadData];
        
        
    }];
}